# TypeScript declarations for API response containing an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

Here is my piece of code:

```
type Data = {
  data: Response;
}

type Response = {
  data: Cards[]; 
}

type Cards = {
  name: string;
}

class Editor extends Component<Props> {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { cardUnderEdition } = this.props;
    const description = cardUnderEdition && cardUnderEdition.currentCard.description;
    const currency = cardUnderEdition && cardUnderEdition.currentCard.name;

    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker') //eslint-disable-line
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data: Data) => this.setState({
        data: Object.values(data.data),
        description: cardUnderEdition === undefined
          ? ''
          : description,
        currentCurrency: cardUnderEdition === undefined
          ? Object.values(data.data)[0].name
          : currency,
      }));
   }
```

I've got an error `Property name does not exist on type {}` in `Object.values(data.data)[0].name`.
What is the appropriate way to add type checking of "name" property?

After suggested changes, I get `Property name does not exist on type Cards[]`

Comment: if you want to add a property to an object you need to do it like so 
obj['name']='a name'

Comment: That's not the question. Tslint sees that Object does't have property "name" and wants something like this: { name: string }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you currently have things set up, `data.data` is a `Response` object that still has a `data` property.  (You should see this if you hover over the second `data` in your IDE.)  `Object.values(data.data)` returns an array of all the property values of the `Response` object; this array contains a single element which is the value of the `data` property, which is itself a `Cards[]`.  Once you take the first element with `[0]`, you are left with a `Cards[]`, which has no `name` property.

I imagine what you intended was to declare the `data` parameter of your callback as type `Response` instead of `Data`.  Then `data.data` is of type `Cards[]`, the `Object.values` is a no-op and can be removed, and `Object.values(data.data)[0].name` returns the name of the first card.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an interface for your `data` -object

eg.

```
interface IData {
 data: IResponse
}

interface IResponse {
 name: string
}

// attach interface to data-obj
.then((data: IData) => ...
```

You also should type your Components state.

```
interface IProps { ... }
interface IState { ... }
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
...
```

Comment: type Data = {
  data: Response;
}

type Response = {
  data: Cards[]; 
}

type Cards = {
  name: string;
}
But now I get Property name does not exist on type Cards[]. There is data in data, that's right.

Comment: @Nikronis Can you please add the latest version of your code to the question so we can see exactly what you tried?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen added